# accessing html elements BeautifulSoup Python2.7

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting all of this html's href class attribute value in a list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I can't even access the reference.

The below is a snippit of what I'm trying to parse:

```
 <!-- <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div id='location_list'><h2>Browse by location</h2><ol class='suburb_locations'><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/abbotsford-nsw">abbotsford, NSW</a><br><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/abbotsford-vic">abbotsford, VIC</a><br><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span>
```

I'm trying to get a dict of key=place and the value = number of active borrowers in one list. And a list that contains the href values. My biggest problem is that I'm not able to access any of these siblings. I've tried a lot of things below is a list of a few codes I've been trying:

```
    from bs4 import Beautiful Soup   
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
    print soup.find_all('br')
    print soup.find_all('div h2 ol li')
    print soup.find('li',{'class':"col-sm-3"})
```

Comment: What are you able to access? ... The `<!--` might cause issues perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `<!--`, if you print soup you will see there is nothing there and when you remove it you get the html.

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

In [4]: print(soup)


In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html.replace("<!--",""),"lxml")

In [6]: print(soup)
<html><body><div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="location_list"><h2>Browse by location</h2><ol class="suburb_locations"><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/abbotsford-nsw">abbotsford, NSW</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/abbotsford-vic">abbotsford, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li></div></ol></div></div></div></div></body></html>
In [6]: soup.select(".col-sm-3")
Out[6]: 
[<li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/abbotsford-nsw">abbotsford, NSW</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li>,
 <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/abbotsford-vic">abbotsford, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li>]

In [7]: soup.select(".col-sm-3")[0].text
Out[7]: u'abbotsford, NSW0  active owners0  active borrowers'
```

I am not sure where you are getting the html from but you need to clean it if you want to parse it.

The conatiner is completely commented outbut you do a replace of just the opening `<!--` in the source we can then pull section:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/find-a-car/")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.replace("<!--",""))

print(soup.select("div #location_list"))
```

Which gives you:

```
[<div id="location_list"><h2>Browse by location</h2><ol class="suburb_locations"><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/abbotsford-nsw">abbotsford, NSW</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/abbotsford-vic">abbotsford, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">0  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/aberfeldie">aberfeldie, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/sa/adelaide">adelaide, SA</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li></div><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/act/ainslie">ainslie, ACT</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/aireys-inlet">aireys inlet, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/airly">airly, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/airport-west">airport west, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li></div><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/vic/albert-park">albert park, VIC</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">5  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/sa/aldgate">aldgate, SA</a><br/><span class="sub_title">1  active owner</span><span class="sub_title">2  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/alexandria">alexandria, NSW</a><br/><span class="sub_title">1  active owner</span><span class="sub_title">53  active borrowers</span></li><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com.au/car-rental/nsw/alexandria-mc">alexandria mc, NSW</a><br/><span class="sub_title">0  active owners</span><span class="sub_title">1  active borrower</span></li></div><div class="row"><li class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.carnextdoor.com
```

And a whole lot more, basically everything of interest in that commented section.

Comment: Well that explains why I'm not able to get anything. I'm reading it straight from the website, and there's a print out like that. You're saying I should just clean it up that way?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Yep,  it is completely commented out in the source so bs4 is going to ignore it

Comment: when you replace you get an "AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'replace' " How do you suggest I get around this?

Comment: @FancyDolphin, I added how to do it

Comment: Out of pure interest, I know you might not know or there are so many reasons, but what are a few reason that part would be commented out?

Comment: @FancyDolphin,  I was trying to figure that out myself, I thought it may have been dynamically loaded but  I don't see anything in the source that suggests it is, it is also styled which is a bit weird. If you uncomment it in chrome dev tools or firebug you can see what it actually does.